# 'Read' status of the message in Django chat built with django-channels

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

How can I show read or unread status of the message for the user? I thought about store IDs of messages seen by user - too much info to store. Maybe store tuple(first_seen_message, last_seen_message) - much less memory in use, but we have many chatrooms and direct messages - all messages get IDs in common pull. How to do it?

I haven't tried anything in particular, bc I have no idea howto :D

UPD: I did it through linking message with users that NOT read it with m2m - less memory in use. On message creation I add all users that should read message and when one read message, I remove this m2m relation object for current user-message pair

Comment: Basically you are just going to wait to use a javascript function on the page that activates when a user disconnects and takes all the texts inside each message div and prints them to a websocket that reads the values into the database and sends emails/create documents from there

Comment: Yes, but js sends me message ids - not texts. And the problem was how to store that information and show how many unread messages do you have and to paginate on them correctly (when you open the page you get the oldest unread messages first)